# Import data into MongoDB error

Tags: mongodb, csv, nosql

Hi I was going to import a csv dataset into MongoDB here is the code for command line: 
 `mongoimport --type csv --headerline --db mflix --collection movies_initial --host "mflix-shard-0/mflix-shard-00-00-l8vxb.mongodb.net:27017,mflix-shard-00-01-l8vxb.mongodb.net:27017,mflix-shard-00-02-l8vxb.mongodb.net:27017" --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --username analytics --password analytics-password --file movies_initial.csv` 
    However, I got an error:

> Failed: error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL
>   authentication step: bad auth Authentication failed.
>   2017-10-29T15:25:25.241-0500  imported 0 documents

Could anyone teach me why this happened?

Comment: Are you sure that you provide the correct login data?

Answer (score 1):

when you use attribute `--host` then just specify host no need to specify other details.

Try the command below:

```
mongoimport --type csv --headerline --db mflix --collection movies_initial
            --host  mflix-shard-00-00-l8vxb.mongodb.net:27017 
            --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --username analytics 
            --password analytics-password --file movies_initial.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing similar work and the below code worked for me.

```
mongoimport --host <CLUSTER>/<SEED_LIST> --ssl --username <USERNAME> --password <PASSWORD> --authenticationDatabase admin --db <DB NAME> --collection <COLLECTION NAME> --type <FILE TYPE> --headerline --file <PATH WITH FILE NAME>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26182268)